# Who First Considered This Generalization of the Fibonacci Numbers?

Tags: soft-question, math-history, fibonacci-numbers, mathematicians

I am looking for the author who originally researched a generalization of the Fibonacci numbers, which Koshy, in Chapter 7 his book *Fibonacci and Lucas Numbers with Application* refers to as the *generalized Fibonacci sequence*.

This simple generalization enables one to consider Fibonacci-like sequences with arbitrary starting values.  As a result, the Fibonacci and Lucas numbers are just two specific cases.

The generalized Fibonacci sequence is defined as:

$G_n=G_{n-2}+G_{n-1}=aF_{n-2}+bF_{n-1}$

where $G_1=a$, $G_2=b$, and $F_n$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number.

Koshy provides an enormous list of references, but he doesn't attribute this generalization to any one in particular.

I am really hoping some one can point me towards the original paper that discusses this generalization. I would think it would be an older paper considering it is the simplest of generalizations and many more complex generalizations were first considered in the 60's and 70's.

Thanks in advance for any help, it will be much appreciated.

Comment: don't now. Note we also have $$ G_n = c F_n + d L_n  $$ for other constants $c,d.$